# Why must initialization value of field members be determinable at compile time?

Tags: c#

1) Why must initialization value of field members be determinable at compile time?

2) But if the  initialization value needs to  be determined at compile time, then why am I able to initialize a `A.b` field using a reference to  an object:

```
class A
{
     B b = new B(); 
}

class B {}
```

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I just initialised a class member with DateTime.Now and it worked fine, even thought the DateTime.Now can't be calculated at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused; there is no such rule for fields. In particular, fields are explicitly initialized *anyway* - either by your code, or to the type's default. The only corner-case is explit struct field initialization, in which all fields must be assigned before the struct is considered complete.

I wonder if you are talking about "definite assignment" of *variables* within methods; i.e.

```
void Foo() {
    int i;
    Console.WriteLine(i); // not valid; i not assigned
    i = 1;
    Console.WriteLine(i); // would be value
}
```

This is so that for method variables the values never suffer from random values picked up from the stack. Actually, there is an IL marked that means that locals are wiped - and IIRC the C# compiler includes this marker *anyway*... but the language spec says method variables **must** be definitely assigned.

---

In the case of you example, that field-initialization *essentially* becomes part of the common constructor code. But you'd never notice it.

Comment: "In the case of you example, that field-initialization essentially  becomes part of the common constructor code." Are you implying that constructor initializes the A.b field?

Comment: @flock: yes, that's what he means.  The assignment statement actually gets moved into the constructor.  Easy to see with Ildasm.exe

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why must initialization value of field members be determinable at compile time?

It mustn't. Why do you think that ?

Comment: Why do you think that? If you have a field initialiser `int i = 7;`, which is determinable at compile time, will the compiler give an error saying it mustn't be determinable at compile time?

Comment: From book Illustrated C# 2008 : "The field initialization value must be determinable at compile time"

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but it appears that instead of up voting  I've accidentally down voted you. I apologize if that is the case

Comment: @flockofcode, if you voted (up or down), the arrow will be highlighted

Comment: @Pete Kirkham, no, that's not what I mean... but I'm not a native English speaker, so perhaps I misused "mustn't". I just wanted to say that the OP's statement was incorrect

Comment: "@flockofcode, if you voted (up or down), the arrow will be highlighted" Now the up arrow is highlighted, but at the time I wrote that comment you had -1, so I assumed...

Comment: I know it's not probably what you meant, but it is what the answer says.  The opposite of saying that something must happen is not saying that it must not happen, but saying that there is no such restriction.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this part of the book [Illustrated C# 2008](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Y--AOWQCG3cC&lpg=PP1&dq=Illustrated%20C%23&pg=PA71#v=onepage&q&f=false), then it is in the section talking about `const` fields. The compiler may replace the use of a const field with the value of the const field, so the initialiser for the field must be constant.

The field in your original post is not a const. Therefore the restriction does not apply to it.

Comment: "If you mean this part of the book Illustrated C# 2008, then it is in the section talking about const fields" No, what you're talking about is on page 71+. My quote is taken from page 50, under the title Explicit and Implicit field initialization

Comment: @flockofcode Then it's wrong. Submit a correction at http://apress.com/book/errata/778